How to make root mount as shared persistent?
I need to use distrobox. But every time I restart the system, distrobox warns me that my root is not a shared mount.
WARN[0000] "/" is not a shared mount, this could cause issues or missing mounts with rootless containers

I have use mount / --make-rshare every time.
Is there a way to make this persistent? I am using Ubuntu 24.04 with systems.
